# Loading shapefile into CartoDB throws 2001 error?

Tags: shapefile, carto

I've been trying to load shapefiles (that are zipped in windows compressed folder) into CartoDB and I always get an error 2001.

These shapefiles were exported out of an ESRI geodatabase (SQL Server).  I believe they are in the correct projection - Web Mercator auxilliary sphere.

Has anyone had a similar experience or might know what is happening?

Comment: Are you attempting to load them from *within* the zip file? Generally that doesn't work, particularly with shapefiles, as the only thing actually pulled out of the zip is the file selected (and there are multiple files to a shapefile). You'll need to extract the zip file to a folder first if you haven't done so.

Answer (score 1):

Contacted CartoDB -- I was using the wrong projection.  I needed to use geographic/world/web mercator.